# How to test a sprites rotation in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-2.x

I want to stop an action once my sprite gets to a certain rotation. For example:

```
CCAction *rotateUp = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.3 angle:-35];
[player runAction:rotateUp];

if (player.rotation == -35) {
    [player stopAction:rotateUp];
    [player runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.5 angle:65]];
}
```

Once the player gets to the max rotation I want it to run a different action. But this isn't working. What can I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get Action output immediately. So it's good to give completion callback for that.

for ex. (in c++)

```
   CCAction *rotateUp = CCRotateTo::create(0.3f, -35f);
   CCCallFuncN *pCall = CCCallFuncN::create(callfunc_selector(<#_SELECTOR#>));

  player->runAction(CCSequence::create(rotateUp, pCall, NULL));
```

Here SELECTOR specified get called when rotation action gets completed. Just convert it in Obj C and try.

Comment: @ErikOhlin12 Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.